# Could not find transform-api.jar

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, transform

I had a project which synced succesfully in last update of Android Studio . Its about 3 days that I update my android studio to version 3.3.2. After that, I can make a new project successfully but can't sync any of my last projects I don't know why.

And the error is

> ( ERROR: Could not find transform-api.jar
>   (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
>   ).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had this following problem in my Android Studio Setup.

When I do the below steps these are causing the problem.

First Step

`settings-->Gradle-->Android studio-->click Enabled embedded Maven repository.`

Second Step

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asus.recyceler_buti"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27`
```

Final Step

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your internet connection, and if that is fine, check for the "offline work" in Android studio settings (if checked, uncheck this):

[image]

And then sync with Gradle.

Comment: I did it and uncheck the offline mode but it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Add these 4 lines to 2 parts of the project according to the photo [please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsL66.png)

Comment: Please post code as a code block into the post. Makes it much easier to work with.