# Gradle sync failed in Android studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

after upgrading my android studio to version 3.6.1 I cant sync Gradle with the android studio I try a lot of ways,
like change Gradle version and sync or download directly Gradle from [gradle blog](https://gradle.org)
but still, I see this error

```
   Gradle sync failed: Could not find transform-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0- 
   deprecated-use-gradle-api).
   Searched in the following locations:
   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated- 
   use- 
   gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

even I download transform-api from above link and put it in the folder of Gradle

and this is my screenshot

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you post your app level, project level gradle files?

Comment: my Gradle version is 3.6.1 and 5.6.4   as  this link I config it :https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin   I try another version but still I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

First clearly declare google maven repo like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59924870/7765316)

If it didn't work, Try these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55021563/7765316)

Answer (score 0):

Open project structure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmiVl.png)

then, open Gradle version drop down and select latest gradle version
and click on Apply. it did work